# SQLCop tests for tSQLt

Tags: sql-server, redgate, tsqlt

The Redgate tool `SQLTest` for SQL unit testing now offers the ability to add tests from [SQLCop](http://sqlcop.lessthandot.com/detectedissues.php) however the Redgate tool only comes with few of those tests prebuild.

Since tests are just stored procedures I am sure somebody has implemented more of those tests.

Are you willing to share? Anyone?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I wrote SQLCop.  I've been working with the fine folks over at Redgate.  Originally I provided 5 (or so) tests as a proof of concept.  Since then, I have also provided the remaining tests that are included with SQLCop.  You should expect the remaining tests to be included in their next release of SQL Test.

Comment: Since they are all just stored procedures and could live separately form the red-gate tool - would you be willing to share them before red gate? The issue is that as much as i like red gate tool i am looking more into implementing tests as a part of my continuous integration rather than running them from management studio via SQLtest. By the way - great work on the SQL Cop - I love it!

Comment: Did you know that you can run SQLCop in a command line mode?  At a command prompt, type "SQLCop -?".  This will show you the command line arguments available.  I modeled the command line arguments after SQLCMD.  Anyway... you could create a batch file with the appropriate command line arguments that sends the output to a file, and then use windows task scheduler to execute the task on a schedule.

Comment: Here is a link to 48 SQLCop tests. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58229865/SQLCop%20Tests.zip

Comment: Another approach is to run tSQLt tests as part of your CI process. Dave Green's article describes how to configure this: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/using-sql-test-database-unit-testing-with-teamcity-continuous-integration/

Comment: @GMastros It seems as though the most recent version of SQLCop does not support command prompt usage.  I typed in "SQLCop -?" in PowerShell and it opens the GUI.  I also tried --?, --help, -h, -help, /help, and --h as flags

Comment: @GMastros Thanks a lot. Could you tell is this the latest version of tests?

Comment: Yes.  That is the latest version of tests.

Comment: @GMastros The dropbox link is dead now, do you have a new one?

Comment: Ignore me, just found this: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/87t6m3ed5tbh27b/AADW6-gu6jL3E6_dwTyCI5poa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I've had SQLCop-type tests on my list of things I should get round to implementing, but have thus far only really implemented some 'test coverage' tests, which are pretty specific to our naming conventions here.

I do note that SQL Test is a preview product from Red Gate, so hopefully there will be more tests in the full release. From reading http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sqlcop-integration-with-red-gate (and a couple of comments on the below forum link) it looks promising. EDIT: George's comment above confirms this.

You could consider logging the request at the forum that Red Gate link to from their website for feedback - http://sqltest.uservoice.com/forums/140716-sql-test-forum

If I do get some more generic tests written soon for my own purposes, I'll certainly share them.

Comment: If you have written tests that you would like included with SQLCop, let me know and I will consider including them.