# SQLCop tests for tSQLt - new

Tags: sql, sql-server, unit-testing, redgate, tsqlt

There was a question about having SQLCop stored procedures as tSQLt tests. And that request was answered with the link to the Dropbox with a zip file. However the link is not working anymore. RedGate page is also referring to the same DropBox link.

I am wondering is it still possible to get those stored procedures or are those under any more strict license than it was before.

The link to previous discussion: 
[SQLCop tests for tSQLt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898865/sqlcop-tests-for-tsqlt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the new link.  Apparently, DropBox changed some things a while ago and I didn't realize it caused problems with the link.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/87t6m3ed5tbh27b/AADW6-gu6jL3E6_dwTyCI5poa?dl=0

This project is now on github [SQLCop on GitHub](https://github.com/red-gate/SQLCop)